# Distinct with join that has same column name

Tags: sql

this is a  question online and i cant seem to get the expected output.

TABLE : `dogs`

```
  id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
```

TABLE : `cats`

```
  id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
```

it is to find the distinct name of this 2 table.

expected output is this

```
-- name     
-- -----
-- Bella    
-- Kitty    
-- Lola
```

i tried join and distinct resulting in saying my name is ambiguous. tired union but cant get to distinct it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the `distinct` list of names you can use `union`

```
select name from dogs
union 
select name from cats
```

or if your database supports `FULL OUTER JOIN` then

```
select distinct coalesce(d.name,c.name)
from dogs d
full outer join cats c on d.name = c.name
```